# Linq to Entities group concat

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Database schema:
Staff has multiple Asset. 1 Asset has 1 AssetModel

I write up a script by Linq that return IQueryable

```
var q = from staff in this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data
        from asset in this.unitOfWork.AssetRepository.Data
                         .Where(asset => staff.Id == asset.StaffId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from assetModel in this.unitOfWork.AssetModelRepository.Data
                         .Where(assetModel => asset.AssetModelId == assetModel.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        group new { staff, assetModel }
           by new
           {
                staff.Id
               ,staff.Name
               ,AssetModelType = assetModel.Type
           } into g
        select new StaffQuery
        {
           Id = g.Key.Id,
           Name = g.Key.Name
           AssetStatistic = (g.Key.AssetModelType == null ? AssetType.None.ToString()
                                            : g.Key.AssetModelType.ToString()) + g.Count()
        };
```

I'm using OData to easy filter, order, select, paging Data Result. 
The below is what I got from OData

```
{
   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52052/odata/$metadata#staffs",
   "value":[
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"John",
         "AssetStatistic":"CaseOrLap2"
      },
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"John"
         "AssetStatistic":"Monitor1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to group concat by AssetModel.Type like the below result

```
{
   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52052/odata/$metadata#staffs",
   "value":[
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"John",
         "AssetStatistic":"CaseOrLap2, Monitor1"
      }
   ]
}
```

It must be return IQueryable and string.Join in this context is invalid because Linq to Entities cannot resolved it.

Comment: It's a waste of time to try finding the way of group concat. It also impact performance of query if we have large data. I work around by creating an table to hold report data. Its data is triggered in somewhere else to keep it updating. It make code clean and easy to maintainance and reusability. Absolutely, my way maybe is not correct in some context and need to adapt to change.